# Regular expression to substring a string with double quote

Tags: java, regex

This may sound a direct question but I am new to Regex in Java.
All I want is like, I have a String like below(It's a whole String).

```
[["name1", "link whaterevercom"],
 ["name2", "link whatevercom2"]]
```

I want is an array of String containing `{name1,link whatevercom, name2, link whatevercom2}`
I can achieve this by substring and loop and that boring way. I know `split()` method supports Regex.
Can anyone help me achieve this by Regex?

Any help will be very appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `split()`, you can do:

```
String input = "[[\"name1\", \"link whaterevercom\"],[\"name2\", \"link whatevercom2\"]]";
String[] split = input.replaceAll("\\[|\\]|\"","").split(",\\s*");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get rid of the brackets and split on ", ":

```
String s = "[[\"name1\", \"link whaterevercom\"], [\"name2\", \"link whatevercom2\"]]";
s = s.replaceAll("\\[|\\]","");
String[] arr = s.split(", ");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr)); 
// prints: ["name1", "link whaterevercom", "name2", "link whatevercom2"]
```

Comment: If you're going to separate the replace brackets, use the plaintext `replace()` and don't escape `s = s.replace("[","").replace("]","");`, *or*, if you're going to use regex replace, combine them: `s = s.replaceAll("\\[|\\]","");`. I would also in-line the `split()` so it's a one-liner.

Comment: @Bohemian try: `s = s.replace("[","");` and you'll get: "java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index..." but you're right that the two replaces can be done via one regex, I'll update my answer - thanks!

Comment: No you won't, because `replace()` does **not** use regex! It uses plain text.

Comment: Wrong again! `replace()` replaces *all* occurrences, just like `replaceAll()`. The *only* difference is that the search term is not regex. You're not the first person to assume that because it doesn't have "all" in its name that `replace()` only replaces one occurrence.